# Check if user already likes my fanpage without user.like permission

Tags: php, facebook

I have checked a lot of solutions but all of them was 'old' it means that now - facebook want to get 'user.likes' permission.

There is not other idea to check that user like my fanpage without getting this submission ('user.like') ?

Answer (score 2):

You are correct. There is no way to check if someone liked your page without user_likes permission. But you should also be aware that like-gating is not allowed by Facebook Platform Policy so there is no need to try to use user_likes because it will never be approved